# how to unload a dynamicly loaded DLL

Tags: c#, dll

I have a DLL written in c# that I load in my client like this :

```
string moduleFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()) + @"\ReportGarage.dll";
string functionName = "GetReportName";

ObjectHandle moduleInstance = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(moduleFileName, "ReportDLL.ClassReport");
MethodInfo mi = moduleInstance.Unwrap().GetType().GetMethod(functionName);
string reportName = Convert.ToString(mi.Invoke(moduleInstance.Unwrap(), null)); 

MessageBox.Show(reportName);
```

This works like I expect it, but I cannot find how to unload this DLL again.
So my questions are :

Do I need to unload it ?
What happens if I don't and I call this code a few times ?
If I need to unload it, how ?

Maybe I need to load/unload in some other method than above, I dont know.
The DLL is also written by me so I can make any changes if needed.

edit:
Let me explain what I need (to avoid the xy problem).

What I am trying to do is write a windows service that looks in a specific folder for DLL's and then tries to load them and call a method (method name will be the same in each dll)
Then I can write a new DLL and just drop it into this folder and it will be picked up by the service.

EDIT:
The duplicate question sounds promising, unfortunate the accepted answer only has a link where I cannot find the article mentioned.

Comment: why do you want to unload the dll??? Maybe your questions tend to be a xy-problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: why don't you simply add the class dll as a reference and use the constructor instead of doing this over reflection?

Comment: @Mat I need to write a windows service that can look in a folder and try to load every DLL found there (all will have exact same method naming). Since this will happen every x minutes it might be needed to unload the DLL's. I don't know that is why I am asking

Comment: @Mat I can then write new dll and just put it in the folder and it will be picked up

Comment: sounds like a plugin system to me... So if dll get deleted you want to "unregister" all related classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plugin architecture in .net: unloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429828/plugin-architecture-in-net-unloading)

Comment: @Mat I am not sure what you meand with "unregister". I dont register any class in my code above I think

Answer (score 3):

One loaded in an appdomain, an assembly cannot be unloaded. You can only unload the entire appdomain using [appdomain.unload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload(v=vs.110).aspx).

> I need to write a windows service that can look in a folder and try to load every DLL found there (all will have exact same method naming). Since this will happen every x minutes it might be needed to unload the DLL's.

You should load each assembly into its own appdomain, and then unload the appdomain.

Comment: I am going to read up on this. Maybe there is a working example somewhere?